# Finding depth of a data point in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

**This is homework. Do not post only code.**

I need to find the depth of a given data point in a Binary Search Tree. I've implemented a `depth()` method and a helper method, `countNodes()`, which recursively counts the nodes.

In the event that the data we're searching for doesn't exist in the tree, I need to return `-1`. I don't see how that's possible given my recursion.

```
@Override
public int depth(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data is null");
    }
    //FIXME don't use the contains() method
    return countNodes(root, data);
}

/**
 * Helper method counts teh nodes
 * @param  node the node we're going to start counting at
 * @param  data that we're looking for
 * @return the sum of the number of children nodes
 */
private int countNodes(BSTNode<T> node, T data) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (compare(data, node.getData()) == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) < 0) {
        return 1 + countNodes(node.getLeft(), data);
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) > 0) {
        return 1 + countNodes(node.getRight(), data);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to check if the recursive functions return -1, and if so also return -1.

Comment: @lared Do I need to put that check in the recursive method? or in the standard method?

Comment: In the recursive one, otherwise you'd overwrite it (IIRC you just added `1` there).

Comment: @lared Which line? [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/xyE2u6xr). I've been trying it everywhere it makes sense, and it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to take into account every single line where you call the function recursively, so also in `else-if`s (since the -1 has to propagate "up")

Comment: @lared Then [this would be what you had in mind, right?](http://pastebin.com/6P9Rm6ey). It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please note when the function is going to have to return `-1` first (as in the deepest).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70602/discussion-between-nxt3-and-lared).

Answer (score 0):

The general idea in this kind of situation is to bring the "not found" status, in this case `-1`, back up the recursion tree. You can do it by checking if the recursive calls returned `-1` - if so, you return `-1` up to the top of the call stack, if not you proceed as normal.